# Assign Iframe content to only authorized website

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, iframe, google-analytics

I have a website in which i have a paypal set up, After getting the amount the i will give an embedding code to other websites to use my iframe.
Is there a way to generate unique code for every website?
also i will have to check that only authorised websites are using my iframe.

Comment: Any reason you aren't just going to use a REST API with tokens to authenticate each site trying to access the information?

Comment: Kindly give me link, i'm stuck here.
Thanks for reply.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9773664/rest-api-token-based-authentication to start off with the concept

Comment: Thanks for your help. Any other related article or topic you want me to study?

Comment: Well to start off with, I found this set of video tutorials easy to learn from when I was starting off with my API (using Node.js) - https://egghead.io/lessons/nodejs-first-api-with-node-js-express-and-mongodb the rest are mostly free but some in between are for pro users.  I'm not sayin you gotta buy a subscription but there's quite a bit of content there you might benefit from and it's not a bad price.