# Global authentication solution for an app using a REST API

Tags: php, android, rest, authentication

My team and I are currrently developing a mobile app with 2 frontends : Android, and HTML/CSS and a REST API backend in PHP.
We want to implement a global authentication, by global I mean usable on both platforms and can allow authenticating with any king of email adresses.
We tried GoogleToolkit for Android and Google Client for PHP, but we can't get user info from the gmail adresses in the first case, and we can't authenticate with other emails in the web version.
I read articles about OpenID, but it seems to be deprecated.
We are definitely lost.

So basically, what we need is an authentication system that uses any email address and provides at least the Name of this user.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried Facebook / Twitter oAuth?

Comment: No, the application has a professional context, we don't want to bring social media elements to its authentication because of the bad impression it could give.

Comment: the authtification system should be based on Service REST to do so you can create in your database a token witch will contain all data of all connected users this token should be indexed by a hashed key take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9773664/rest-api-token-based-authentication

Comment: That is what we are planning to do when having more time, for the moment we are developing a beta-version that has to be ready in a few days, so we are looking for ready-to use libraries.