# Authentication approach for REST API used by frontend app and another backend service

Tags: javascript, java, rest, microservices

I have a rest api backend service **A** which is used by two other services:

- **B** service which is web app running in a browser (separate node server)
- **C** service which is also backend service (separate server too)

My initial approach was to use basic auth for A-B communication but this does not make sense for A-C since there is no way to safely keep credentials in a browser. On the other hand introducing session and tokens seems weird for A-B communication.

No matter what I do it seems like tug of war.

What do you think might be reasonable solution for such setup?

Comment: I tink you could try to use Oauth2 https://oauth.net/2/ authentication. In simple words: the autenthication generates a token. This token can then be used from the clients to authenticate the user/client without passing arround username and password.

Answer (score 0):

You need at least SSL for A-B and then only you can judge if basic auth works or not.

If C is going to use the same APIs as B then it makes sense to use the same authentication methods, just for simplicity, IMO.

You could also use a token based auth mechanism where each service (remote or local) authenticates and gets a token and uses that for subsequent communication.

See the following for more:

[REST API Token based authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9773664/rest-api-token-based-authentication?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to AWS API Gateway for clues on how to implement authentication for REST APIs.
https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/faqs/#security

Summary:

1. Access Token
2. Custom Authentication
3. Enable CORS
4. Client side SSL certificate based authentication